# wp7:Is it possible get autometically trigger when my location is changed?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am trying to create tracing application.In this application i am using location tag.

So Is it possible to automatically get a trigger or message on particular event on location change?
i.e:
I would like to know if a user has moved in a new location. If the user has moved I would like to trigger a specific event from my application. Is it a specific WP7 service which can inform my application that the user has changed his location and trigger an event from my application?

My concern is that if user change location at that time i want to call one web service and send this location data to my server.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are asking about is called 'geofencing'. The Windows Phone APIs do not support this out-of-the-box, but it is pretty easy to implement this yourself. Google for 'geofencing windows phone', you will find a number of articles like this one:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dragoman/archive/2010/10/13/wp7-code-geofencing-with-the-geolocation-api-and-rx.aspx

Comment: :thanks for replay but when my application is not running at that time how can i get latitude and longletitude? if my app is running at that time i will do with GeocoordinateWacher position changed event but what about when my application is not running

Comment: With windows phone 8, geolocation apps can run in the background: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521530/A-Windows-Phone-8-Run-Tracking-App-in-100-Lines-of

Comment: :Thanks again but not possible in wp7?

Comment: :my concern is what when my application user change position at that time i want latitude and longitude of particular user. so i can use this lat and long for giving notification to my user. this all thing will be done by web service part. i just want to find which event give me lat and long when user change its position and i mean which event is fire when user change position.